# Find a particular element of an html page using Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have multiple levels of div class elements out of which I need to find just a particular elements and get the text value and store in a variable.

```
<div class="Serial">
<p> … </p>
<p>
<span>
    <a href="mailto:xyz@xyz.com">
        Mr. XYZ
    </a>
</span>
</p>
<p> … </p>
<p> … </p>
```

So, we have 4 different paragraphs out of which I need to only read second paragraph and save the email ID to a variable. When I use the following code,

```
find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Serial']")
```

I get all the 4 paragraph information. Is there anyway I can specify which paragraph to read within the div class? I know for sure the order doesn't change and I only want to read 2nd p element. Appreciate your help.

Comment: If you're having trouble getting the correct xpath, I would recommend trying out [cssselect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect) which converts CSS selectors to xpaths. Might make it easier to work out which element(s) you are selecting.

Answer (score 0):

You could try accessing the `<p>` tag by giving `xpath` as `find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Serial']/p[2]/span/a")` to access the email id present in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not completely correct to rely on order of paragraphs - one day it may change, and those who will come after you can be slightly confused by p[2]. As you need to find text from paragraph with email link, I believe this XPath would do the trick:

```
//p[span/a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto:')]]
```